# How to re-export types as global in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface, export

I would like to have an interface (defined in a separate file) be accessible globally, how do I do this?

Here's my `globals.d.ts` file

```
import { Theme, Style } from './style/themes/theme.types'

declare global {
  Theme
  Style
}
```

This gives me an error

```
Statements are not allowed in ambient contexts.ts(1036)
'Theme' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
```

Comment: There are a few hacky solutions, like importing under an alias and then declaring a global type alias, `import { Theme as TM } from './style/themes/theme.types'; declare global { type Theme = TM; }`, but that's awkward and not exactly what you've described. Why are you doing this? What's the use case? It seems highly suspect.

Comment: It is suspect, I think it's just better to define the types in the type definition file than to try to import them

Comment: You're confused. Whether the file is a `.d.ts` or a `.ts` has nothing to do with whether you import them or not. I would answer your question if I could make sense of it.

Comment: Yea I think my question doesn't make sense, I'm gonna post my solution to the problem when I get the time.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a hack as this raises an error if placed inside a `.ts` file but seems to work when placed inside a `.d.ts` file.

The idea is to import the type with one name and export with another.

`src/globals.d.ts`:

```
import type { DeepPick as _DeepPick } from "ts-deep-pick";
declare global {
  export { _DeepPick as DeepPick };
}
```

Comment: To add to this, you can `export interface Theme extends _Theme`. Useful in scenarios when you want to extend an interface of a library like Emotion https://emotion.sh/docs/emotion-11#theme-type

Comment: As for me, even in .d.ts file there is still error. Just add a `// @ts-ignore: export typing` line before it.

Comment: This solved my issue of using Express.Multer.File in my app library where tsc complained about I'm using a non exported File interface.