# ASP.NET 5 (Core) Website with TypeScript and Node (or ESM) modules in Visual Studio [not Code] 2019?

Tags: node.js, typescript, asp.net-core, npm, asp.net5

So I have followed [this guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-core.html) to setup TypeScript in a ASP.NET 5 website project (with Razor Page). I want to have TypeScript typings with Node modules instead of just importing as `any`.

Now I want to add a Node module, like EthersJS, so I have:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "ethers": "^5.4.1"
    }
```

This code would not compile:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";

export class EthService {

    pro: ethers.providers.BaseProvider;

    constructor() {
        const pro = this.pro = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider("");
    }

    async getBlockNumberAsync() {
        return await this.pro.getBlockNumber();
    }

}
```

unless I add `"moduleResolution": "Node"` to `tsconfig.json`. Obviously this wouldn't actually run in a browser.

How should I set it up so the Node module get compiled somehow? I think the problem can be solved if I can do either of these:

- Make TypeScript/Gulp/MSBuild change `import { ethers } from "ethers";` into proper path (I can copy the compiled lib file manually into wwwroot).
- Manually set import path to `import { ethers } from "path/to/compiled/ethers.js";`, but I need to somehow tell TypeScript that that `ethers` typing is from `ethers` Node module.

UPDATE: I think a third possibility is very nice as well if I can just have a declare import (I will just add the ESM file into the global scope) like this:

```
declare import { ethers } from "ethers";
```

Is any of the above option possible? Or is there any way? Thanks.

Note: I know there is [Triple-Slash Directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) and it may solve my problem but I don't really understand what they do yet.

The current `gulpfile.js`:

```
/// <binding AfterBuild='default' Clean='clean' />
/*
This file is the main entry point for defining Gulp tasks and using Gulp plugins.
Click here to learn more. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518007
*/
var gulp = require("gulp");
var del = require("del");
var paths = {
    scripts: ["Scripts/**/*.js", "Scripts/**/*.ts", "Scripts/**/*.map"],
};
gulp.task("clean", function () {
    return del(["wwwroot/Scripts/**/*"]);
});
gulp.task("default", function () {
    gulp.src(paths.scripts).pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/Scripts"));
});
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "Node"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the problem by using a standalone `ethers.js` script file to expose `ethers` namespace to the global scope:

```
<script defer src="/libs/ethers.umd.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Now you need to tell TypeScript that there is an `ethers` "thing" (namespace/module) in the global scope. I found a solution thanks to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973864/how-to-re-export-types-as-global-in-typescript/66588974). Create a `.d.ts` file (any will work, I name it `globals.d.ts`):

```
import { ethers as eth } from "ethers";

declare global {

    // @ts-ignore: export typing
    export { eth as ethers };

}
```

Now you can use `ethers` anywhere without needing any declaration. For example my whole `EthService.ts` file:

```
export class EthService {

    pro: ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider;

    init(server: string) {
        this.pro = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(server);
    }

    async getBlockNoAsync() {
        return await this.pro.getBlockNumber();
    }

}
```